# Updating the contents of a MergeAdapter

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have a pretty nifty MergeAdapter that contains a bunch of custom views and some custom ListAdapters.  This MergeAdapter drives a ListActivity that displays content that get's updated every x seconds.

Currently I just create a new MergeAdapter, create and add all of my custom views (and this includes a few ImageViews) - and call setAdapter on the ListView in my activity.

After about 10 minutes of updates I run out of heap space and crash.

Ultimately because a new ImageView is added, and the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

With simpler adapters (like ArrayAdapter), I would just update the data set, and call

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on the adapter.

Is there a similar/recommended approach for "updating" a MergeAdapter? Or should I be walking the contents of a potentially complex MergeAdapter and updating individual Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a similar/recommended approach for "updating" a MergeAdapter?

`notifyDataSetChanged()` works, AFAIK. The current `MergeAdapter` has the code to ripple any changes from `ListAdapters` inside it to whatever has registered interests in changes in the `MergeAdapter`. This probably has not been tested enough, so if you have a sample app that demonstrates otherwise, post a link to it or send it to me (mention this SO question).

Comment: I am using Custom Cursor adapters for my single listview .I try to merge two cursor adapter into one single listview. I want to refresh listview after result come from server.But mergeAdapter does not refresh.

Comment: FeedQuestionCursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(
     FeedQuestionProvider.FEED_QUESTION_URI, null, null, null,
     null);
   QuestionAdapter.changeCursor(FeedQuestionCursor);
   QuestionAdapter = new FeedQuestionCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
     FeedQuestionCursor);
   lv_earn_question.invalidate();
   // QuestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   ((BaseAdapter) QuestionAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @CommonsWare: Im using MergeAdapter to merge different Views and SimpleCursorAdapters. As you said notifyDataSetChanged updates any ListAdapters. But is there a workaround to update the Views? Please help.

Comment: @abhijit.mitkar: Call methods on your `Views` to change what they look and behave like. There is no means in `MergeAdapter` to replace them, though that is something that could be added.